# Can't assign a value to gameobject in a child class through inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have classes `Function1`, `Function2` and so on who inherit from a `Functions` class and attached to separate prefabs. And the `Functions` class has a variable of type Movement named target which is attached to a gameobject called `Character`.

For example I attach `Function1` to a prefab in hierarchy and drag `Character` onto target variable and it just works fine. But when I pull prefab to project folder, the variable target returns to None type. Movement is a singleton. I just use GetComponent in `Function1` script and it works. But I can't understand why I can't assign the value through hierarchy.

By the way, I need the `Character`'s transform for path finding.

Comment: You can't reference anything in your scene from your prefabs, so when you create a prefab out of an object, it clears any such invalid references. You'll either need to rework how you're structuring things, or programmatically find the reference at runtime.

Comment: But I referenced things in the scene before. The problem rised after I used child classes. Before, I only had one script and was able to reference things in the scene in the prefabs.

Comment: In the situation of referencing scene objects from prefabs, this is unlikely - to this day, [this has not been possible](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135209/how-to-store-references-to-scene-objects-in-prefabs/135221) in the Unity editor. Prefabs can reference prefabs, and scene objects can reference scene objects and prefabs. Those are the relationships currently possible in the editor - anything else will need to be done through scripting.

Comment: Thanks now I understand it.